# Get all Posts with Self-Accepted Answers in SEDE (Stack Exchange Data Explorer)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, dataexplorer

As stated in the title, we're looking to get all Posts (including Users, Comments and Suggested Edits) where the original question-asker accepted their own answer as the best answer. In other words, all cases where `OwnerUserId for PostTypeId 1 = OwnerUserId for PostTypeId 2`.

I'm struggling with this as I don't have a deep understanding of the `SEDE DB` schema.

This is from `SEDE` examples that gets Users with high self-accept rates (and having > 10 answers) but we need the Posts with Self-accepted answers, not just the users.

```
SELECT TOP 100 
  Users.Id AS [User Link],
  (
    CAST(COUNT(a.Id) AS float) / 
    CAST(
      (
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM Posts p 
        WHERE p.OwnerUserId = Users.Id 
        AND PostTypeId = 1
      ) 
      AS float
    ) * 100
  ) AS SelfAnswerPercentage
FROM Posts q
  INNER JOIN Posts a ON q.AcceptedAnswerId = a.Id
  INNER JOIN Users ON Users.Id = q.OwnerUserId
WHERE q.OwnerUserId = a.OwnerUserId
GROUP BY Users.Id, DisplayName
HAVING COUNT(a.Id) > 10
ORDER BY SelfAnswerPercentage DESC
```

Comment: If you really want to get: (a) all answers on such questions, (b) all comments on the questions and its answers, (c) all (suggested) edits on all those posts, and (d) the usernames for all of the preceding; then you will time-out SEDE and quickly reach the 50K row limit before you get even a small fraction of that data.  Your best bet is to download the data dump and go to town on that.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. We just need the latest 10k records only, starting from today.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your expected output?  And the schema of your tables?

I'm not familiar with your DB schema, but this could be a starting point:

```sql
SELECT q.*
FROM posts q -- Get all posts
INNER JOIN posts a ON q.AcceptedAnswerId = a.Id
  AND q.OwnerUserId = a.OwnerUserId AND a.PostTypeId = 2 -- Get accepted self-answers
INNER JOIN users u ON u.Id = q.OwnerUserId -- get OP's user info
WHERE q.PostTypeId = 1 -- Only get questions
```

I'm not sure where your `comments` & `suggested edits` are stored, but I'm guessing you will need to do some kind of `group_concat()` or JSON-type aggregation to return that data if you only want one row per question post.

Comment: Thank you for providing the Code. They don't have a specific Schema laid out, I guess. But here's the Documentation for querying it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede

Comment: Thanks, that helps.  I updated my response.  How do you want your output to look - one row per post with summarized comments / edits data?  Or do you want multiple result sets - one for posts, comments, suggested edits?